# Microsoft WorkFlow tracking long running process on other computers

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have read a great many posts about WF and am very impressed by what it claims to do.  I've been reading documentation and white papers and am also intimidated by the learning curve.  I have a rather different requirement than most developers who have been asking the “Will WF work for me” question though.  Most of the posts focus on human speed tasks: get an email, put together an order, send information to warehouse and billing and wait for their responses and so forth down the workflow persisting information when waiting for choices and taking the event from a person to continue the processing.

However, in my case humans are observers only.  We have a lot of developers running VERY long running tasks on number crunching computers (somewhere between 36 and 48 hour long number crunches).  The human interaction would be setting up the parameters for an execution, hitting a button to queue it up (if the crunching machines are busy) and then observing the resources used by the process and wait for it to complete.  Users aren't going to keep their application open for days, so persisting the information when they close or requesting it when they open the client is important.

I like the idea of WF taking care of the persisting information and being able to take care of the queue (though when we move to a priority queue, I’m sure I’ll have to write the priority metric), but I don’t know how it would work with holding onto a System.Diagnostic.Process object to track a running process on a remote machine.  And if it did, could I get the state information of the process (memory, CPU demand, time running) when needed?